View in Browser link only showing plain text
The 'view in browser' link on a mailing sent via CiviMail is only linking to plain text view. Is there a way to link out to the Public View (design and layout that recipients can otherwise see in their inbox)?

Normally the HTML view is the one that this links to. It sounds like something isn't working quite right here. Could you edit your question to add more details of your setup - e.g. CiviCRM version, CMS version, whether you are using Mosaico or traditional mailings etc.
